# Ionic 3 select option style css

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

How can I put that ion-select box bigger?

Should I leave it wider?

[image: image here]

**CODE**

```
<ion-item style="padding-left: 30px!important;padding-right: 30px!important;max-width: 300px;" >
   <ion-select   class="mastersA"   [(ngModel)]="option"   style="max-width: 50px;">
      <ion-option selected="true"  value="100ltc">100% LTC</ion-option>
      <ion-option  value="100mic">100% MIC</ion-option>
      <ion-option  value="50ltc50mic">50% LTC + 50% MIC</ion-option>
   </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: change `padding-left: 30px!important`  to `padding-left: 30px !important` and same for padding-right

Comment: Not work bro...Not much has changed ... img -> https://imgur.com/a/tObzwRA

Comment: try `ion-item{padding:0}` in your css.

Comment: mastersA  class css update

Comment: why  keep inline style with max width on ion-select?

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your ion-select :

`style="max-width: 100%;width: 100%;"`

```
<ion-item style="padding: 0px 30px!important;" >
<ion-select class="mastersA" [(ngModel)]="option" style="max-width: 100%;width: 100%;">
  <ion-option selected="true"  value="100ltc">100% LTC</ion-option>
  <ion-option  value="100mic">100% MIC</ion-option>
  <ion-option  value="50ltc50mic">50% LTC + 50% MIC</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```